# Simple jquery autocomplete input box not working

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am trying to implement autocomplete feature on an input textbox. I have copied all the code and it doesn't seem to work. This is the same code from jquery website(autocomplete example) Any help?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

//console errors

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///C:/resources/demos/style.css
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined /C:/Users/Saad/Desktop/tHome.html:11
```

Any help?

Comment: Your code works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xU3UP/. Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: check path of jquery librarary

Comment: works here also -> http://jsfiddle.net/eHr74/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xU3UP/1/ -- Working here!!!

Comment: I have updated the question. Console errors..But why? it is opening the jquery files via view source

Comment: Are you testing this locally or on a server? If locally, change the URLs for the includes to use http://.

Comment: I am testing it locally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

for this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

The problem is you're testing it locally you need to add the http at the beginning for it to work

Comment: great...Its working now...No console errors now. Why http causing files failed to load?

Comment: if you don't add the http: part, the browser will use the protocol you're using currently and since you're testing it locally it will look for file:// and code.jquery.com is not in your file system

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src=" HTTP: //code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Or you delete http: because of StackOverflow ?

Comment: Why -1 ? My answer is good... "RR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file://code.jquery.com/..."

Comment: I don't know who gave you -1 vote, but your answer is correct.